# Cycles render appears not to render on GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

Lately I bought a Radeon GPU to speed up my rendering proces, but I didn't notice a significand decrease in rendering time. I checken my processes and my GPU only used about 2% of its capacity, while my Intel used about 75%. Which is strange because i turned off the use of my Intel in my preferences. I tried rendering a different scene; same results. I all the latest drivers and stuff; still no change.
I already set my tiling to 256 x 256, so that can't be it.

The equipment i use:

- Blender 2.90
- Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz

So my question is, is blender using my GPU at all? And if so, is there any way i can make blender use more of my GPU?

My GPU stats while rendering a heavy scene.
[image: My GPU stats while rendering a heavy scene.]

My CPU stats while rendering a heavy scene.
[image: My CPU stats while rendering a heavy scene.]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check settings: Edit->Preferences->System->CyclesRenderDevice

Since I run on NVIDIA mine are different but you graphic card needs to be check marked in one of the tabs.

[image: Settings for my NVIDIA]

Furthermore, check out recent guides for speed improvement. Most important tip is the tiling. For GPUs it should be larger than for CPU.

Comment: I've already done all of that. I will put that in my original post. Thanks anyway.